# False url helper for Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have a controller mounted at the root of an Engine with the same name

```
module Contacts
  class ContactsController < ApplicationController
   ...
  end
end

Contacts::Engine.routes.draw do
  root 'contacts#index'
  resources :contacts, :path => '/'    
end
```

So I get the expected routes:

```
         root GET    /                   contacts/contacts#index
     contacts GET    /                   contacts/contacts#index
              POST   /                   contacts/contacts#create
  new_contact GET    /new(.:format)      contacts/contacts#new
 edit_contact GET    /:id/edit(.:format) contacts/contacts#edit
      contact GET    /:id(.:format)      contacts/contacts#show
```

However I have a small problem with my Model:

```
module Contacts
  class Contact
    include ActiveModel::Model 
    include ActiveModel::Serialization
    ...
  end
end
```

Looks like my `link_to` insists in using the false url_path, and I am not sure where I can fix the relationship between my model and the url helpers of my controller:

```
link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @contact]
NoMethodError: undefined method `edit_contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc421e17e08>:0x007fc41ca4c8f0>
```

Why is the plural form for the `:edit` path being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @contact]` is incorrect. Rails detects the action from the state of the `@object`. What's happening is that Rails interprets `:edit` as a namespace.

```
link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @contact]
```

See the [polymorphic documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html).

I'm not sure you can generate an edit polymorphic route in that way. And if you can, `:edit` should be after the resource. Example (I haven't tried it)

```
link_to 'Edit', [@contact, :edit]
```

I suggest you to use the explicit route name

```
link_to edit_contact_path(@contact)
```

I don't see any advantage in your case to use the polymorphic route.